# How to import an external C library?

Tags: c, graphviz

I want to use GraphViz as a C library(cgraph) but I don't know how to actually "import" it.
The folder contains *makefile.am*, so I should use automake to get a *makefile.in* file. Where do I go from there?

I'm really confused on the actual procedure to follow.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: @kirjosieppo I'm using ubuntu 20.4

Comment: Where did you get the source from? Usually the source should contain a `Makefile`, and there should be no need to faff around with automake.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, there are several makefiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just share my experience. I have no permission to post a comment, thus I post an answer for your reference. I am using ubuntu 20.04.

In the beginning,

```
foo.c:4:10: fatal error: graphviz/cgraph.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <graphviz/cgraph.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Then, I install graphviz-dev and it works.

```
$ sudo apt-get install graphviz-dev
```

If this is not the answer you expected, please let me know. I will remove this post. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you. Although I'd like to know why that works, does it place the headers and *.c* files in the gcc directory?

Comment: @G.Ajello https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libgraphviz-dev/filelist There’s a list of the files installed.